# Logon to external website from my website with my login/passwd, without let users know them

Tags: javascript, php, apache, any

Is there any way to logon to an external website , with my own login/password,without letting users know my login/pass.
I used to submit the logon form from the JavaScript ,but the token of "Cross-site request forgery"  made this impossible.
I also tried ReverseProxy::FormFiller ,but with no success.
Is there any other way to do that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends what other 'other site' allows you to do. Can you send a curl login check? http_post as file_get_contents request? This is too wide to answer correctly. But the short answer is: yes, of course you can. Somehow.

Comment: In order to do cross request your request origin must be allowed in "other site" api .

Comment: You could likely make use of a curl call to to it.

Comment: yes i can with curl , but i want the users to be logged in , in their browsers ,and navigate the external browser as a normal member .

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on